# Fetch all JSON files in a specific directory located in the public HTML in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, typescript

I currently have a project structure that looks like this:

```
- Root
    - node_modules
    - public
        - Parent
            - FolderA
                - FileA.json
                - FileB.json 
                - ...
                - FileN.json (1 <= n <= 100)
            - FolderB
            - ...
            - FolderN (1 <= n <= 30)
        - FolderIds.txt
    - src
```

Using 'fetch' I load in the "FolderIds.txt" file which has information on each folder in the "Parent" folder (specifically the folders name). This file is a text file with a new entry on each line.

```
fetch('/Parent/FolderIds.txt').then((result) => {
    result.text().then((txt) => {
        // Code to read the contents into a react state variable (already done)
    });
})
```

Example from the 'FoldersIds.txt'

```
FolderA-PriorityA-DisplayNameA-ListOrderA
FolderB-PriorityB-DisplayNameB-ListOrderB
...
```

The above code works flawlessly.

**OK, now my question**

My next step is be able to fetch all files and their contents in a specific folder. So let's say I click a button for folder "FolderB" (which was obtained using the aforementioned text file) the code should give me an array of each file name in that folder. It's fine if it doesn't give me the contents as I can just use 'fetch' on each name to achieve that.

Unfortunately, I can't use 'fs' as it causes issues with create-react-app and webpack. Is there a fix for this? Does anyone know if I can use 'fetch' to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Only server side code can read/enumerate a directory’s contents (for security)

Comment: booo. Lol, makes sense though. How would you recommend I handled this then? I tried pulling them from github but the api limits the amount of calls you can make and I have a feeling it will be used quite often. My current idea is to write a script that makes 1 api call to github to load it into a blob storage or equivalent database which I can run whenever the repo is updated.

Comment: Don’t know sorry.  There are modules out there that detect GitHub repo changes, but I’m not exactly sure what you’re doing when a change happens.